# Is it possible to pre configure a summary link webpart in a custom page layout with several links?

Tags: sharepoint-designer, web-part, page-layout

I created a custom page layout with SharePoint Designer for use as a new default or welcome page in a publishing site. The page layout should contain a summary link web part that is pre configured with a list of links. SharePoint Designer already has some sample links included in the webpart and I modified them as needed. The preview also in SharePoint Designer shows just what I need. But when I create a new page, using my custom page layout, in my SharePoint site, it has the summary link web part but empty without the links.

```
<PublishingWebControls:SummaryLinkWebPart runat="server" Description="Externe Datenquellen" 
ListDisplayName="" HelpLink="" AllowRemove="True" IsVisible="True" AllowHide="True" UseSQLDataSourcePaging="True" SummaryLinkStore="" 
ExportControlledProperties="True" DataSourceID="" Title="Externe Datenquellen" ViewFlag="0" NoDefaultStyle="" AllowConnect="True" FrameState="Normal" 
PageSize="-1" AsyncRefresh="False" ExportMode="All" PartOrder="2" DetailLink="" ShowWithSampleData="False" ListId="00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000" 
FrameType="TitleBarOnly" PartImageSmall="" PartImageLarge="" IsIncluded="True" SuppressWebPartChrome="False" AllowEdit="True" ManualRefresh="False" ChromeType="TitleOnly" 
AutoRefresh="False" AutoRefreshInterval="60" AllowMinimize="True" ViewContentTypeId="" Dir="Default" InitialAsyncDataFetch="False" MissingAssembly="Cannot import this Web Part." 
HelpMode="Modeless" ListUrl="" ID="g_9ff5513e_80b2_4c71_92c3_49c7db485df8" ConnectionID="00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000" AllowZoneChange="True" IsIncludedFilter="" 
ZoneID="" __MarkupType="vsattributemarkup" __WebPartId="{9ff5513e-80b2-4c71-92c3-49c7db485df8}" WebPart="true" Height="" Width="">
<DataFields>
</DataFields>
<SampleData>
<dsQueryResponse>
                    <Rows>
                        <Row Title="Item1" LinkUrl="http://Item1"  Order="2" BeginColumn="False" IsGroupHeader="False" />
                        <Row Title="Item2" LinkUrl="http://Item2"  Order="3" BeginColumn="False" IsGroupHeader="False" />
                        <Row Title="Item3" LinkUrl="http://Item3"  Order="4" BeginColumn="False" IsGroupHeader="False" />
                        <Row Title="Item4" LinkUrl="http://Item2"  Order="3" BeginColumn="False" IsGroupHeader="False" />
                        <Row Title="Item5" LinkUrl="http://Item2"  Order="3" BeginColumn="False" IsGroupHeader="False" />
                        <Row Title="Item6" LinkUrl="http://Item2"  Order="3" BeginColumn="False" IsGroupHeader="False" />
                    </Rows>
                    </dsQueryResponse>
                  </SampleData>
<Xsl>
    <xsl:stylesheet xmlns:x="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" 
    xmlns:cmswrt="http://schemas.microsoft.com/WebPart/v3/Publishing/runtime" exclude-result-prefixes="xsl cmswrt x" > 
        <xsl:import href="/Style Library/XSL Style Sheets/Header.xsl" /> 
        <xsl:import href="/Style Library/XSL Style Sheets/ItemStyle.xsl" /> 
        <xsl:import href="/Style Library/XSL Style Sheets/SummaryLinkMain.xsl" /> 
    </xsl:stylesheet>
</Xsl>
```

Answer (score 0):

You would need to use the SummaryLinkStore property of the webpart to store the preconfigured data.

Comment: Can you please extend this answer with some information about how to use that property, it will make your answer more helpful :)

Answer (score 0):

This is an old question but I'd like to share something because I experienced same issue and spent some time to figure out the issue.
What I noticed is, the summary links become visible only after checking in a page. I am not sure why it is.